# LaTex table corner cell line not showing

Tags: latex, overleaf

I'm using Overleaf to write a report. I can't seem to get the format just right for the top right corner cell.
I would also like to center "Correlation coefficient"

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Correlation coefficient between force plate data and kinematic model data}
\label{IMUvsVB}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c||c|}
\hline
\textbf{Ground reaction} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Correlation coefficient}} \\
\cline{2-3}
& \textbf{IMU based kinematics} & \textbf{Vision based kinematics}\\
\hline
Anteroposterior &   0.91 &  0.96\\
Mediolateral &  0.80 &  0.79\\
Vertical &  0.97 &  0.99\\
Frontal &   0.64 &  0.66\\
Sagittal &  0.91 &  0.94\\
Transverse &    0.82 &  0.84\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute

```
\textbf{Ground reaction} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Correlation coefficient}} \\
```

with

```
\textbf{Ground reaction} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Correlation coefficient}} \\
```

The `\multicolumn` command needs 3 inputs:

- The 1st one is the number of columns to be spanned.
- The 2nd is the formatting of the cell (`l` for left, `c` for center and `r` for right). Here you can add also `|` for a single vertical line or even `||` for a double vertical line.
- The 3rd one is the content of the cell.

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) if you need more insights on the usage of `\multicolumn`.